# FAQ mentions "Android Market"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, faq-proposed

From the [help center's list of off-topic subjects](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Issues with the Android Market from the point of view of a developer or publisher

The "Android Market" isn't even a thing any more. Should we update this text? What should it say?

Answer (score 8):

I propose that that line should instead read:

> Issues with Google Play (or any other app marketplace) from the point of view of a developer or publisher

This way, we get to make it clear that issues with Amazon App Store etc. (from the POV of a developer) are also off-topic.

Comment: I accept this change. I made a slight modification: "Issues with *the* Google Play *Store* (or any other app marketplace) from the point of view of a developer or publisher"